# UIButton in custom UITableViewCell not registering tap

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcode-storyboard

I have a custom UITableView, with custom UITableViewCells that are dynamic in height. I create the skeleton of the custom cell in storyboard, which includes (for simplicity) just a label at the top (static height), a label in the middle (dynamic height), and a label at the bottom (static height).

I have a tap gesture setup on the bottom label.

The problem I am having, is the tap gesture on the bottom label does not work (all the time). It seems to work when the middle label is shorter (2 lines), than when it is longer (2+ lines). If I move the label to the top, and anchor it to the top of the superview, the tap event gets registered every single time.

Has anyone else experienced this, and perhaps has a solution to this problem?

It seems to work fine if I add the label programatically.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your bottom label is not occluded by the label in the middle? Labels have default transparent background, maybe your bottom label is visible but not accessible for tap gestures. Try downsizing your middle label or add tap gesture compatibility to middle label also so that you understand if it takes away the tap gesture from the bottom label. If this is case you can fix it by bringing bottom label to front

```
[tableCellView bringSubviewToFront:bottomLabel];
```